# How do i play different audio for different image buttons when i click on them?

Tags: javascript

I tried this code but it only plays one sound.

```
         <script>
  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }

     function play2(){
       var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
       audio.play();
                 }           




   </script>

<img src="mages/ah.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="bgmusic.mp3" ></audio>
<img src="images/a.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio2" src="war.ogg" ></audio>
```

I am trying to play different sounds for different images that are clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<img src="mages/ah.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="bgmusic.mp3" ></audio>
<img src="images/a.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio2" src="war.ogg" ></audio>
```

javascript

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
  function play(){

    audio.play();
    audio2.pause();
  }

  function play2(){
    audio.pause();
    audio2.play();
  }
```

Comment: can you check your video path and id it's perfect or not.

HTML file location & Audio file location in the same folder or not place chek it.

also check your browser support audio or not check out.

Answer (score 0):

you could call audio2.play() in function play2 and call play2() on your image onclick handler

Update: Playing the ogg file in Safari maybe doesn't work

https://caniuse.com/#search=ogg

And you are referring to different image folders

And the img tag has no 'value' attribute in Spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to the code, please call the right function on image click and play right audio in that function.

```
 <script>
    function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
                 }

     function play2(){
       var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
       audio2.play();
                 }           
</script>

<img src="mages/ah.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="bgmusic.mp3" ></audio>
<img src="images/a.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play2()">
<audio id="audio2" src="war.ogg" ></audio>
```

Comment: i have tried changing audio.play(); to audio2.play(); and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: i also changed it to audio2.play2(); and it did nothing.

Comment: don't do audio2.play(2), it won't work, have you also changed the onlick in second image to `onclick="play2()"`  ?

Comment: Great, glad to know it helped. Also if the issue you were having is solved then you can accept the answer which you find suitable so that more focus can be put on questions which still don't have any right answers, Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
function play2() {
   var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio2");
   audio.play();
}
```

you declared `audio2` but you play `audio`.
And here:

```
<img src="mages/ah.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio" src="bgmusic.mp3" ></audio>
<img src="images/a.png" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">
<audio id="audio2" src="war.ogg" ></audio>
```

both handlers call `play`. You have to take care of these typos and check that each one calls the correct function: `play()` or `play2()`.

Another way is to pass to the js function also the `id` of the tag where you want to retrieve the source:

```
onclick="play('audio');"
```

and

```
onclick="play('audio2');"
```

so you can use only one function:

```
function play(id) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    //
}
```